# Best real-time solution device ( iPhone ) vs server side

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, real-time

i'd like to stream raw datas from server to iPhone in real-time mode. is there any good solution for this? 
My app should be able to graphically present measurements pushed from the server in real-time. 
thanks

Comment: You don't say what the data is, how much of it there is, what format it's in... The iPhone has a radio and a CPU so it's functionally possible. Whether it's practical or not it's impossible for anyone to say.

Comment: Like Stephen says, it's surely possible in some form, with some performance, using some protocol.  Why not have a go and see what happens?  See if you can do it with HTTP and the browser on the phone?  AJAX?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I want to push real-time measurements data such as -> galvanic skin response measured by biometric system in our university. therefore my app have to be able to accept data of size cca 5KB per second.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say "measurements", it sounds like you have less stringent real-time requirements than, say, VoIP. There are two ways you might consider: 1) push notifications, such as through Urban Airship, or 2) make an HTML5 app and use socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

I found Pusher library -> https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/

Seems like it's the right thing i need to finish my project.
Thanks for your help guys